# Callocing memory

Tags: c, calloc

I'm trying to create a file system and I need to calloc the file descriptors.

Let's say I have two structures with the following definitions:

```
#define DESCRIPTOR_MAX (256)
#define TABLE_MAX (32)
```

`typedef struct S16FS S16FS_t;`

```
typedef struct {
    bitmap_t *fd_status;
    size_t fd_pos[DESCRIPTOR_MAX];
    inode_ptr_t fd_inode[DESCRIPTOR_MAX];
} fd_table_t;

struct FS {
    back_store_t *bs;
    fd_table_t fd_table;
};
```

I'm callocing a new file system with no problem:

```
FS_t *fs = (FS_t *)calloc(8, sizeof(FS_t));
```

but my problem arrises when I want to calloc the `fd_table` within the `FS` struct.   Here's what I'm trying.

This one produces no errors:

```
fs->fd_table = *(fd_table_t*)calloc(TABLE_MAX, sizeof(fd_table_t));
```

I'm getting an error with the following:

```
fs->fd_table.fd_pos = (size_t *)calloc(TABLE_MAX, sizeof(size_t));
```

> error: array type 'size_t [256]' is not assignable

Can someone explain to me what i'm doing wrong or if I'm just completely wrong in my process? Do I even need to calloc the `fd_pos`?

Comment: Should we just *guess* what `FS_t` is ? And Fyi, putting any dereferenced allocation on the right side of an assignment in a single statement is a recipe for a memory leak. This: `fs->fd_table = *(fd_table_t*)calloc(TABLE_MAX, sizeof(fd_table_t));` makes no sense at all, and leaks memory while doing it.

Comment: oh you know, I forgot to add a typedef. I'll edit my question

Comment: That's what I figured. It was producing no errors but it felt horribly, horribly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `fs->fd_table.fd_pos` is an array, not a pointer.  If you want a dynamic array, then change the type to `size_t*`.

Otherwise, it's perfectly fine to leave it as an array and not use dynamic allocation.  In that case, if you want to zero the memory (as `calloc` does), you can just use `memset`:

```
memset( fs->fd_table.fd_pos, 0, sizeof(fs->fd_table.fd_pos) );
```

Oh yes, and also WhozCraig points out that your first example is a leak (allocating memory, then dereferencing and copying, followed by losing the pointer).  In fact, you don't need to `memset` as I suggested above because the entire structure was zeroed with the first `calloc`.

Comment: Ah! That makes so much more sense. So I can avoid using the memset, but how should I edit the first calloc to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: OH! The very first calloc! I don't need to be calloc-ing what's inside the `FS_t` because the initial calloc took care of the zero-ing, correct?

Comment: The first `calloc` being the one where you allocate and zero some memory for 8 structures (pointed to by `fs`).  That one's fine.  The other two `callocs` are not required.  In fact, they were only affecting the first of those 8 structures anyway.

Comment: Yes that makes sense now. Thank you for your responses!